# Selecting specific 5 row in a list of XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a list of 10 items as shown in the XML below.

```
<books_standing bestsellers="My Book" total="10">
  <book book_id="4" book_name="Book 4" copy_sold="41" position="1"/>
  <book book_id="14" book_name="Book 14" copy_sold="38" position="2"/>
  <book book_id="23" book_name="Book 23" copy_sold="33" position="3"/>
  <book book_id="1" book_name="Book 1" copy_sold="30" position="4"/>
  <book book_id="4" book_name="Book 4" copy_sold="28" position="5"/>
  <book book_id="25" book_name="Book 25" copy_sold="27" position="6"/>
  <book book_id="13" book_name="Book 13" copy_sold="24" position="7"/>
  <book book_id="7" book_name="My Book" copy_sold="20" position="8"/>
  <book book_id="8" book_name="Book 8" copy_sold="19" position="9"/>
  <book book_id="2" book_name="Book 2" copy_sold="18" position="10"/>
</book_standing>
```

What I want to do is to select a specific row, and then show 2 rows on top and 2 rows below.  I want to show the the book name title "My Book" which is currently in 8 position.  What I want to show "My Book" in between of 2 data above and below.  My out example is Position, Book Title & Copy sold.

```
6  Book 25 27
7  Book 13 24
**8  My Book 20**
9  Book 8 19
10 Book 2 18
```

I'm able to pull the data, but not sure how to focus on that particular book that I need.

```
class BookStanding
  {
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string CopySold { get; set; }
  }

System.Xml.Linq.XDocument _xdoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(responseAsString);
var bookData = from books in _xdoc.Descendants("book")
            select new
               {
                  book_id = books.Attribute("book_id").Value,
                  book_name = books.Attribute("book_name").Value,
                  position = books.Attribute("position").Value,
                  copy_sold = books.Attribute("copy_sold").Value
                };

            ObservableCollection<BookStanding> MyBookStanding = new ObservableCollection<BookStanding>();

            int bookIdx = 0;
            foreach (var books in bookData.Take(10))
            {
                BookStanding mBookStanding = new BookStanding();

                mBookStanding.BookId = Convert.ToInt32(books.book_id);
                mBookStanding.BookName = books.book_name;
                mBookStanding.Position = Convert.ToInt32(books.position);
                mBookStanding.CopySold = Convert.ToInt32(books.won);

                MyBookStanding.Add(mBookStanding);

                bookIdx++;
            }
            BooksListBox.DataContext = MyBookStanding;

            BooksGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Thanks!

Credits to @Nir Smadar for helping me out on this one.  The solution given by him was after the loop put these codes in.

```
var BookPosition = MyBookStanding.Single(b => b.Book_Name == "My Book").Position;
var selectedBooks = MyBookStanding.Where(b => b.Position <= BookPosition + 2 && b.Position >= BookPosition - 2);

BooksListBox.ItemsSource = MyBookStanding;
BooksGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the items you end up with a collection of books 'MyBookStanding'. 
Now you need to find the position of the selected book:
var bookPosition = MyBookStanding.Single(b => b. book_name == whateverBookName).position;

And finally the 5 books: 
var selectedBooks = MyBookStanding.Where(b => b.position <= bookPosition + 2 || b.position >= bookposition - 2);

Sorry for not formatting my answer- I'm typing from my cell..

Comment: So do I add this right after the for each loop like so? `var bookPosition = MyBookStanding.Single(b => b.book_name == "My Book").position;  var selectedBooks = MyBookStanding.Where(b => b.position <= bookPosition + 2 || b.position >= bookposition - 2); BooksListBox.DataContext = selectedBooks;`

Comment: I did as what you say. But it's still showing all 10 books.  Is there something where I went wrong?

Comment: Debug your code- how much books are in selecteBooks?

Comment: Oh, now I see that you ussed tbe DataContext property of the list box. Instead use the itemsssource property.

Comment: **bookPosition = 8** while **selectedBooks System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[MyBooks.BookStanding]**

Comment: The MyBookStanding collection should not be an obsevablecollection. Those are not good with linq queries.

Comment: Oh ok. What should I do instead?

Comment: If it's not bound to the ui, a simple list will do. (We're kind of polluting the debate here- the original question was answered)

Comment: Lol. My bad.  Missed out on our item Source property.  Tried that, but it still shows 10 results.  Will try and it out.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi. Figured out what went wrong, should use the && operator instead of the ||.  Thanks so much for your help. Appreciate it!